# pytelegrambotapi. Как проверить есть ли участник в группе?

Tags: python, django, telebot

Доброго времени суток!

Использую библиотеку `pytelegrambotapi`, он же `telebot`

Есть вот такой кусочек кода:

```
 if text == '➕ Подписаться на канал':
        mes = 'Подпишись на этот канал и вернись чтобы получить вознаграждение!'
        keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        url_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти к каналу", url="google.com")
        callback_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Проверить подписку', callback_data='check_subscribe')
        keyboard.add(url_button, callback_button)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, mes, reply_markup=keyboard)

        user.step = 'subscribe_channel'
        user.save()
        return HttpResponse('OK')

    if callback_data.find('check_subscribe') != -1:
```

После последней строчки мне нужно проверить, есть ли участник в канале/группе. 
(по идее бот будет админом в канале и сможет смотреть список юзеров)
Я не знаю как это сделать, читал документацию но что-то не нашел ничего именно по этой теме :с

Если сталкивался кто с этим, или знает как сделать, подтолкните пожалуйста в правильном направлении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой задачи подойдёт следующий метод: [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember)

Если пользователь присутствует в чате, метод возвращает объект [ChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember)

**Необходимые параметры:**

```
chat_id - ID или @название канала/группы
user_id - ID пользователя
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А не подскажете, если у меня имеется chat и user id, как я могу это совместить? `group_id = '-242022020'
            check = bot.get_chat_member(group_id, chat_id)`
И далее пытался `if check == 'ChatMember' ` - выдавало ошибку
Еще был вариант `if 'ChatMember' in check:`

Comment: ChatMember это объект юзера. Выше я указал ссылку - можно посмотреть какие параметры есть у объекта.